# Get parent instantiated object off complex method chain?

Tags: ruby, class, object

Forgiving the contrived example, if I have...

```
class Condiment
  def ketchup(quantity)
    puts "adding #{quantity} of ketchup!"
  end
end

class OverpricedStadiumSnack
  def add
    Condiment.new
  end
end

hotdog = OverpricedStadiumSnack.new
```

... is there anyway to get access to the `hotdog` instantiated object from within `Condiment#ketchup` when calling `hotdog.add.ketchup('tons!')`??

---

So far the only solution I've found is to pass `hotdog` in explicitly, like so:

```
class Condiment
  def ketchup(quantity, snack)
    puts "adding #{quantity} of ketchup to your #{snack.type}!"
  end
end

class OverpricedStadiumSnack
  attr_accessor :type

  def add
    Condiment.new
  end
end

hotdog = OverpricedStadiumSnack.new
hotdog.type = 'hotdog'

# call with
hotdog.add.ketchup('tons!', hotdog)
```

... but I would love to be able to do this without passing `hotdog` explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be:

```
class Condiment
  def initialize(snack)
    @snack = snack
  end

  def ketchup(quantity)
    puts "adding #{quantity} of ketchup! to your #{@snack.type}"
  end
end

class OverpricedStadiumSnack
  attr_accessor :type

  def add
    Condiment.new(self)
  end
end

hotdog = OverpricedStadiumSnack.new
hotdog.type = 'hotdog'
hotdog.add.ketchup(1)
```

Comment: Thanks; seems obvious now. :)